# iOS using GL_RGBA8

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures

Is there a way to use `GL_RGBA8` on the iPhone/iPad? My textures show up as blank when I try to use `GL_RGBA8_OES` instead. `GL_RGBA` is causing problem when using transparency.

I haven't tried it on the real device, only in the simulator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GL_RGBA8` is for the render buffer. See http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_rgb8_rgba8.txt.

To get 8-bit RGBA textures, when calling `glTexImage2D` use `GL_RGBA` as the format and `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` as the type.

If you have problems with transparency not appearing, make sure `GL_BLEND` is enabled, make sure that `glBlendFunc` is being used to set up the blending properly, and (for GLES 1.x) double check that the `glTexEnv` settings are correct. I think that's everything relevant...

Comment: Just occurred to me, this sort of error might be easier to spot if `glGetError` were used after every OpenGL call. `assert(glGetError()==GL_NO_ERROR)` will do for starters. I touch on this in another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764173/android-opengl-es-i-cant-make-glulookat-gluperspective-work

Comment: Thank you, the problem I had was indeed caused by the absence of GL_BLEND. It now works fine with GL_RGBA.